# I can't create a NAT Gateway

Tags: azure, nat, azure-networking

I have a VNet /16 with 2 subnet /24 (private and public)

In my Public subnet, i have a windows with a public IP. I can access this windows with RDP.
In my Private subnet, I have a Linux with no public IP. I can access this linux from the public windows using putty.

Of course, my linux can't access to Internet with a private IP. So I need a NAT gateway.

I try to deploy a NAT gateway with a new public IP for my private subnet using the Azure Web UI :

1. the public IP creation is OK
2. The NAT gateway stop with an error : "The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Network' for api version '2019-09-01'."

Do you have an idea of what's happen ?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Since you haven't provided much information, we can only guess.  Are you using the right resource group?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a NAT Gateway to access the internet. All VM's can by default access the internet regardless of whether they have a public IP or not. Azure is not like AWS in that regard.
Azure has a NAT Gateway device (it's only been out a few weeks) but this is to handle persistent outbound IP addresses, it is not required to access the internet.

If your Linux VM cannot access the internet I would check the following:

- Ensure you have not amended the Network Security Groups that apply to that VM to disallow internet access
- Ensure the VM is set up to use some DNS servers
- Ensure there are no custom routes that prevent traffic from reaching the internet